# WIRIS plugin not show any formula

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wiris

I have added wiris plugin to my ckeditor and did the configuration but it doesn't show any content when I click on it.

```
var mathElements = [
    'math',
    'maction',
    'maligngroup',
    'malignmark',
    'menclose',
    'merror',
    'mfenced',
    'mfrac',
    'mglyph',
    'mi',
    'mlabeledtr',
    'mlongdiv',
    'mmultiscripts',
    'mn',
    'mo',
    'mover',
    'mpadded',
    'mphantom',
    'mroot',
    'mrow',
    'ms',
    'mscarries',
    'mscarry',
    'msgroup',
    'msline',
    'mspace',
    'msqrt',
    'msrow',
    'mstack',
    'mstyle',
    'msub',
    'msup',
    'msubsup',
    'mtable',
    'mtd',
    'mtext',
    'mtr',
    'munder',
    'munderover',
    'semantics',
    'annotation',
    'annotation-xml'
];

var toolbar = [
        {name: 'wiris', items: ['ckeditor_wiris_formulaEditor', 'ckeditor_wiris_formulaEditorChemistry']},
        {name: 'wiris', items: ['Wiris']},
    ];

    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('ckeditor_wiris', ns.basePath + '/ckeditor/plugins/wiris/plugin.js', 'plugin.js');

var ckConfig = {
        extraPlugins: "image2,uploadimage,mathjax,justify,ckeditor_wiris",
        mathJaxLib: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.4/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML',
        allowedContent: true,
        extraAllowedContent: mathElements.join(' ') + '(*)[*]{*};img[data-mathml,data-custom-editor,role](Wirisformula)',
         removePlugins: 'image,filetools,uploadimage,uploadwidget,uploadfile,filebrowser',
    };
```

when I click on wiris icons in ckeditor, the only sign I have received is that in issues of chrome see this message in this below image that says it is related to same site

[image]